# CSS formatting doesn't apply to new tags created by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a bunch of JS code to add click listeners to the HTML buttons. I have some CSS that applies to the existing HTML. But the CSS doesn't appear to apply to the HTML generated by the JavaScript.

[Link to JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8n0zden/)

As you can see, line 1 has all the proper spacing. But any of the generated lines by clicking any of the three buttons lose the spacing.

Here's the CSS:

```
.form-block {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;

  span {
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance! :)

Comment: The CSS class `.form-block` is applied to the created elements, you can see it by inspecting the code after clicking any of the buttons. I'm not sure what you mean by losing the spacing.

Comment: @AntonioSmoljian If you run the code and click any of the buttons a few time, you'll notice the spacing between the elements are different than the original.

Comment: Off Topic: check out [`<template>` nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) or the [`<script type="text/template">` pattern](/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script) to inject html-templates into the markup and use them in JS.

Comment: @PaulYizhaoChen Yes i noticed later on that you mean the inherit spacing from inline elements. The answer below has outlined all you need fortunately.

Comment: btw, your CSS is broken. CSS itself doesn't support nested tags. That's a feature of LESS, SASS, SCSS and these fellas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see are actual spaces between the elements in your original HTML/row, and then a lack of spaces between the elements in your JS generated elements.

I would either remove the spaces between the elements in your HTML, and use a left/right `margin` value to create that space instead, or add a space or carriage return/new line between the elements when you add them in your JS.

I removed the spaces (by inserting HTML comments) in your original HTML, and added `margin-right: 1em` to the `input` and `button`s in your element row.

```js
/*This function interprets the line position. 
//input is a lpos string which is in the form of x.x.x.x
//splits it by the '.'
//returns the array with position
*/
function lposToAr(lpos) {
  var ar = lpos.split('.');
  for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    ar[i] = parseInt(ar[i], 10);
  }
  return ar;
}

//This function turns the position array back into a string
function lposToStr(posAr) {
  return posAr.join('.');
}

//This function creates a new line after clicking the NL button.
function NL(lpos, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var cLine = document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0].cloneNode(true);
  var cNL = document.getElementsByClassName('new-line')[0].cloneNode(true);
  var cNN = document.getElementsByClassName('new-nested')[0].cloneNode(true);
  var cI = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].cloneNode(true);
  cI.value = '';
  var cNI = document.getElementsByClassName('new-input')[0].cloneNode(true);

  //figure out which position
  var posAr = lposToAr(lpos);
  var clickNode = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < posAr.length; i++) {
    clickNode = clickNode.children;
    var skipCount = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < clickNode.length - 1; j++) {
      if (clickNode[j].tagName != 'DIV') {
        skipCount++;
      }
    }
    clickNode = clickNode[posAr[i] + skipCount - 1];
  }

  //set the last element of the posAr the total number of same level <div>+1
  var siblingDivCount = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < clickNode.parentNode.children.length; i++) {
    if (clickNode.parentNode.children[i].tagName == 'DIV') {
      siblingDivCount++;
    }
  }
  var newPosAr = posAr;
  newPosAr[newPosAr.length - 1] = siblingDivCount + 1;

  //Update the cloned items with the new line info
  var newPosStr = lposToStr(newPosAr);
  cLine.innerHTML = newPosStr;
  cNL.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    NL(newPosStr, event);
  });
  cNN.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    NN(newPosStr, event);
  });
  //cI doesn't need to change, unless there's a bug
  cNI.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    NI(newPosStr, event);
  });

  //Make the new Div
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'form-block');
  newDiv.appendChild(cLine);
  newDiv.appendChild(cNL);
  newDiv.appendChild(cNN);
  newDiv.appendChild(cI);
  newDiv.appendChild(cNI);

  //Add the new Div
  clickNode.parentNode.appendChild(newDiv);
}

function NN(lpos, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var cLine = document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0].cloneNode(true);
  var cNL = document.getElementsByClassName('new-line')[0].cloneNode(true);
  var cNN = document.getElementsByClassName('new-nested')[0].cloneNode(true);
  var cI = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].cloneNode(true);
  cI.value = '';
  var cNI = document.getElementsByClassName('new-input')[0].cloneNode(true);

  var posAr = lposToAr(lpos);
  var clickNode = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < posAr.length; i++) {
    clickNode = clickNode.children;
    var skipCount = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < clickNode.length - 1; j++) {
      if (clickNode[j].tagName != 'DIV') {
        skipCount++;
      }
    }
    clickNode = clickNode[posAr[i] + skipCount - 1];
  }
  var childDivCount = 0;
  for (var k = 0; k < clickNode.children.length; k++) {
    if (clickNode.children[k].tagName == 'DIV') {
      childDivCount++;
    }
  }

  posAr.push(childDivCount + 1);

  //Update the cloned items with the new line info
  var newPosStr = lposToStr(posAr);
  cLine.innerHTML = newPosStr;
  cNL.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    NL(newPosStr, event);
  });
  cNN.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    NN(newPosStr, event);
  });
  //cI doesn't need to change, unless there's a bug
  cNI.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    NI(newPosStr, event);
  });

  //Make the new Div
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.className = 'form-block';
  newDiv.appendChild(cLine);
  newDiv.appendChild(cNL);
  newDiv.appendChild(cNN);
  newDiv.appendChild(cI);
  newDiv.appendChild(cNI);

  //Add the new Div
  clickNode.appendChild(newDiv);
}

function NI(lpos, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //copy text box
  var cI = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].cloneNode(true);
  cI.value = '';
  //find the node that has been clicked
  var posAr = lposToAr(lpos);
  var clickNode = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < posAr.length; i++) {
    clickNode = clickNode.children;
    var skipCount = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < clickNode.length - 1; j++) {
      if (clickNode[j].tagName != 'DIV') {
        skipCount++;
      }
    }
    clickNode = clickNode[posAr[i] + skipCount - 1];
  }
  //add the new textbox
  clickNode.insertBefore(cI, clickNode.getElementsByClassName('new-input')[0]);
}

document.getElementsByClassName('new-line')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  NL(document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0].innerHTML, event);
});
document.getElementsByClassName('new-nested')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  NN(document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0].innerHTML, event);
});
document.getElementsByClassName('new-input')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  NI(document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0].innerHTML, event);
});
```

```css
/**
* Add styling to the form to make it look appealing
*/

.form-block {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

span {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.form-block button, .form-block input {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!--
DO NOT CHANGE THE CONTENTS OF THIS BLOCK
-->

<form class='myform'>
  <div class='form-block'>
    <span class='line'>1</span><!--
    --><button class='new-line'>New Line</button><!--
    --><button class='new-nested'>New Nested Line</button><!--
    --><input class='input' type='text' placeholder='Enter Value...'><!--
    --><button class='new-input'>Add input</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I noticed that the new generated div's were all inline when I logged them in the console. I had a feeling that these might cause a problem. So the unfortunate thing is I'm not allowed to modify the HTML in this project. If i had to add the spaces/new line in JS, how would I achieve this? appending a "br"? thanks!

Comment: @PaulYizhaoChen oh sorry, totally missed that comment that said not to modify your HTML. You can `createTextNode(' ');` to create a space and add that between the elements. https://jsfiddle.net/y8n0zden/2/